# Complicated queries with php

Tags: php, mysql

I got the following tables with some data in them:

```
Products:

+---------------------------+
|id|name |details  |price|cn|
|__|_____|_________|_____|__|
| 1|pen  |somethi  |100  |10|
| 2|paper|something|30   |11|
+---------------------------+

Categories:

+----------------------------+
|id | name      |parent_id   |
|____________________________|
|1  | granny    | 0          |
|2  | dad       | 1          |
|3  | grandson  | 2          |
|4  | grandson 2|  2         |
+----------------------------+

Products2categories:

+-------------------------------+
| id  | product_id | category_id|
|_______________________________|
| 1   | 1          | 3          |
| 2   | 1          | 2          |
| 3   | 1          | 1          |
+-------------------------------+
```

Basically, there are products, categories and a table which match the product to the categories.

As you can see, every product can be related to several categories, just like in the example above where the product with the id of `1` (pen) is related to categories: 1,2,3.

That's how the database is build. 
**NOTE**: there can be ONLY 3 levels per category, which means, `grandson and grandson2` can't be parents.

Now, what I'm struggling with is the `delete` functionallity.

I want to choose from a list a category, the category can be a grandfather category, mabe a father category, or even a grandson category. Once I click on the delete button, I would like to delete the following things:

- the products related to the category
- all of the "son" categories
- all of the products that the "son" categories hold
- remove the prodcut_id and the category_id from the table `Products2Categories`

For example:

If I delete the category `granny` I would like to delete all of the products related to it, then I would like to delete the "son" category which is `dad` and all of the products related to it and unlink it from the table `Products2Categories` then, because `dad` has a "son" I would like to delete his sons, he actually has 2 of them, `grandson and grandson2` and all of the products related to them and ofcourse unlink them from the `Products2Categories` table.

I've been trying to think of a code that can do that for the past 2 days and I just couldn't come up with any idea, I'm pretty much lost.

Thanks in advance!

**NOTE:** If you need *ANY* additional information, please feel free to ask for it!

Comment: Please read about cascade delete and make Fk's according to your needs

Comment: "FK's" ? what's that? I'm pretty much looking to do the delete through a PHP code

Comment: @kfirba [Foreign Key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key).

Comment: I see. 
By doing that, it means I will have to re-create my all tables? or I can just add it now? and if you can, can you send me a link to show me how to do it using PHPMYADMIN?

Comment: @kfirba Go to "Relation view" part. You don't need to recreate the tables but you might need to change the table tibe to `InnoDB` and add index to the columns you wish to create FK for.

Comment: @eric.itzhak Thanks! I've done that. I linked between `categories`.`id` AND `products`.`id` to the corresponding columns in the table `produtcs2category`. 
But! this isnt solving the problem at all, unfortunately.
When I delete the category, all of it's son categories are still exist, and the products are still exist in the `product` table. only the rows in the table `products2categories` that had the category id, are deleted. how do I fix that?

Comment: @kfirba Did you define it to cascade on delete? you need to define FK in both tables

Comment: @eric.itzhak Hey! here are the reuslts so far:
When I delete a product, it's deleting the rows corresponding in `products2categories` as intended.
When I delete a category, it's deleting the corresponding rows in the table `products2categories` but DOESN'T delete the products that are related to the category. Also, it doesn't delete all of the "sons" and the products related to the "sons".

Comment: @eric.itzhak Should I open a topic discussing about the proper DELETE CASCADE for this DB?